# Can you display an image without affecting the Box size?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hey there working on a footer and I want to add an image in certain position however when I add it, it affects the size of the Box (as it should) since I'm placing it inside the box and I wanted to know if it was possible to set it up as a background or behind all the footer if that makes sense without affecting the box.

This is what I have:

```
<Box
        px={{ xs: 1, sm: 6 }}
        py={{ xs: 3, sm: 8 }}
        bgcolor="text.secondary"
        color="white"
      >
        <Container maxWidth="lg">
          <ThemeProvider theme={Oxanium}>
          
            <Grid container spacing={5}>
              <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                <Box borderBottom={1}>
                  <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>Social Media</Typography>
                </Box>
                <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
                  <Box>
                    <IconButton href="">
                      <TwitterIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Box>

                  <Box>
                    <IconButton href="" color="inherit">
                      <FacebookIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Box>

                  <Box>
                    <IconButton href="" color="inherit">
                      <InstagramIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Box>

                  <Box>
                    <IconButton href="" color="inherit">
                      <YouTubeIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Box>

                  <Box>
                    <IconButton href="" color="inherit">
                      <Icon>
                        <img src={TwitchIcon} height={25} width={25} />
                      </Icon>
                    </IconButton>
                  </Box>
                </Box>
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                <Box borderBottom={1}>
                  <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>Gamer Tag</Typography>
                </Box>
                <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
                  <Box>
                    <IconButton href="" color="inherit">
                      <Icon>
                        <img src={SteamIcon} height={25} width={25} />
                      </Icon>
                    </IconButton>
                  </Box>
                  <Box>
                    <IconButton href="/" color="inherit">
                      <Icon>
                        <img src={EpicGamesIcon} height={25} width={25} />
                      </Icon>
                    </IconButton>
                  </Box>
                </Box>
              </Grid>

              <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                <Box borderBottom={1}>
                  <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}> Server </Typography>
                </Box>
                <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
                  <Box>
                    <IconButton href="" color="inherit">
                      <Icon>
                        <img src={DiscordIcon} height={25} width={25} />
                      </Icon>
                    </IconButton>
                  </Box>
                </Box>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <img src={Duskull} height={100} width={100} />
            
          </ThemeProvider>
        </Container>
      </Box>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

This is how it looks without the gif:

[image]

This is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-bardeen-y16yz?file=/src/App.js)

Closest result to what I wanted

```
<Box style={{ right:235, position: "absolute",  alignSelf: "flex-end" }}>
   <img src={Duskull} height={100} width={100} />
</Box>
```

[image]

Anything else just fix it in the page, or in the page corner itself and not that small black box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give the GIF position absolute to take it out of page flow so it won't effect the box style and the footer container position relative so the GIF is still  positioned in the footer then position the GIF with right 0 and top/bottom properties.

Comment: Oh right absolute completely forgot about that, let me check really quickly

Comment: I did the following: `<Box style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 1530, top: 1630 }}>` and that did the trick

Comment: Actually with `right:0, bottom:0, position:'absolute'` it gets on the bottom corner of the page itself but not the box for some reason

Comment: In the end the closest result to what I wanted was the following: `style={{ right:235, position: "absolute",  alignSelf: "flex-end" }}`

Comment: `Actually with right:0, bottom:0, position:'absolute' it gets on the bottom corner of the page itself but not the box for some reason`
Have you applied position relative to the footer container?

Comment: `absolute
The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

This value creates a new stacking context when the value of z-index is not auto. The margins of absolutely positioned boxes do not collapse with other margins.`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position